# how use filter date in directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have date in format ISO8601 and I have to reformat it to format 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss' in directive but it's not working. The date is displayd in original format.

directive:

```
app.directive('createTimeDirective', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div style="font-size: 9px;"> Created at {{date2}}<div>',
        //replace: true,
        scope: {
            date: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var dateFormat = 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss';
            //scope.date = attrs.date;
            scope.date2 = $filter('date')(attrs.date, dateFormat);
            console.log(scope);

        }
    };
});
```

directive usage:

```
<create-time-directive date="'{{notices[$index].CreationTime}}'"></create-time-directive>|
```

Comment: It should be `{{notices[$index].CreationTime}}`, not `'{{notices[$index].CreationTime}}'`. Remove the single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, answer from JB Nizet was good:).

But the full solution is here:

directive usage (removed single quotes):

```
<create-time-directive date="{{notices[$index].CreationTime}}"></create-time-directive>|
```

directive updated:

```
app.directive('createTimeDirective', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div style="font-size: 9px;"> Created at {{date2}}<div>',        
        scope: {
        date: '@'
    },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var dateFormat = 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss';        
            scope.date2 = $filter('date')(attrs.date, dateFormat);            
        }
};
}]);
```